# imagecopyresampled in php -> destination file

Tags: php, gd2

i'm using jCrop and CodeIgniter, trying to make an image uploader.
So i have my image folder and inside a temp folder.
I make the upload to my temp folder and then display the uploaded image with the cropper.
When i submit the form, i go to my php and use the code provided by jCrop:

```
$src = 'demo_files/flowers.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

Nor in here, or anywhere else, i see how to define the destination image path and filename.
I want to keep the original one in the temp folder and create the resized one in the parent folder.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nor in here, or anywhere else, i see how to define the destination image path and filename.

You'll find [the manual page for `imagejpeg()` enlightening](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) -- the second argument, which is `null` in your example code, is the destination file name.

> I want to keep the original one in the temp folder and create the resized one in the parent folder.

Just be aware that the copy in the temporary directory may disappear once the script terminates.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i was only looking in the docs for imagecopyresampled, and i was looking for a function like 'imagesave' or something. Thank you